# LUIS Bot not able to find entity in the user utterance

Tags: node.js, azure, botframework, azure-language-understanding

I am using `EntityRecognizer` to find the `entities` present in the user utterance. I am following the official `NotesApp` example you can find [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-recognize-intent-luis).
I am getting `null` value in the console when i send a utterance present in the LUIS intent. For Example: `create a note of name Note.Title` where `Note.title` is the `Entity`(title of the note).

I am not sure what is the problem here as it is invoking the `dialog` on the matching utterance but not able to find `Entities` or an `Entity`.

The below code should print the title in the console.

```
    .matches('Note.Create', [(session, args, next) => {

        //Resolve and store any Note.Title entity passed from LUIS.
        var intent = args.intent;
        var title = builder.EntityRecognizer.findEntity(intent.entities, 'Note.Title');
        console.log("Title---"+title);

        //extra code ahead...
     }])
```

Comment: Have u trained and published the LUIS app?

Comment: @EzequielJadib yes i have, and its recognizing the intent but not the entites.

Comment: What utterance are you sending?

Comment: @EzequielJadib i am sending- 'Note.Title is my new note to be created'

Comment: so You are sending 'Note.Title'? but that's the name of the entity, you should send some of the values associated with that entity like 'Create my favorites note' or 'I want to create a note of title shopping list'

Comment: No, that was just a utterance i copied from my intent. Sorry for misleading you. I am saying - 'a new note of name sarthaksfirstnote' or 'create a note named sadthaksfirstnote '

Comment: Have you trained LUIS for that type of utterance in the Note.Create intent, and marked sarthaksfirstnote as a Note.Title entity?

Comment: Yes, I have. And that utterance also has a score of 0.98

Comment: See my response, I'm sure you are missing something...Follow the steps I did and you will be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem you are having here is that the note title you are using is not being recognized by `LUIS` as `Note.Title` entity. To solve this, you will have to train `LUIS` for some of those values.

As you can see in the image below, in the plain `LUIS` app after adding the Note domain, your utterance hits the current intent but the title is not being recognized

[image]

So go to the `Note.Create` intent, add your utterance and tag your new title note as the `Note.Title` entity.

[image]

Train the app and voila!

[image]

Comment: Yes, it worked!. Thank You! Though I did same thing before but i did not test the utterance in the batch testing panel. Anyways Thanks for the guidance.

Comment: But what is happening when i specifically tag "sarthaksfirstnote" to User.Title entity, it only maps to sarthaksfirstnote and when i say anything other than sarthaksfirstnote it still has same problem. i have added a phrase lists for that but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, as Ezequiel Jadib mentioned in comment, please check if you [train your LUIS app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/train-test) and publish it.

Secondly, if your LUIS app still doesn't recognize the entities (or intents) correctly, you can label more utterances or [use Phrase lists feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/add-features) to improve your LUIS app's performance.

Besides, LUIS could not be 100% intelligent in all scenarios, for some specific scenario, we can handle it in our code logic, as we can find in code snippet under [“Handle the Note.Create intent” section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-recognize-intent-luis), it will prompt for title if it doesn't detect any `Note.Title` entity passed from LUIS, which give us another way to get the title of note when LUIS app doesn't recognize or detect the `Note.Title` entity from user’s query/utterance.

Comment: nope, no help, I trained the app multiple times and tested the utterances too in the LUIS but no luck. I have also deployed the app into Production slot after every change. Also i rechecked my LUIS ID in Azure Web App Bot. Every thing seems fine. I am getting the intents but not the entities recognized.

Comment: Do you try to [label more utterances](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/label-suggested-utterances)? or use [Phrase lists feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/add-features)? Which should improve your LUIS app's performance.